# Any way to specify the XML string used in xsi:type=""?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlinclude

I have a hierarchy of classes that are serialised to XML using `XMLSerialiser`. To do this I am declaring all the concrete types with `[XmlInclude]`. eg.

```
 [XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
 public class Base
 {
 }

 public class Derived : Base
 {
 }
```

An instance of Derived gets serialised as:

```
<Base xsi:type="Derived" />
```

Is there any way change the type text to something other than the class name? eg:

```
<Base xsi:type="Fred" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do it as follows:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Fred")]
public class Derived : Base
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XmlType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmltype.aspx):

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
public class Base
{
}

[XmlType("Fred")]
public class Derived : Base
{
}
```

This will give you the desired `xsi:type` when serializing a `Derived` object using a `Base` serializer. My test program output:

```
<Base xsi:type="Fred"/>
```